# understanding a number theory related fact

Tags: number-theory

we know that if we want to find out the number of multiple  of a number(x) from 1 to a specific number(n) we divide n by x.For example,if n=1000,x=6 the number of multiple of 6 from 1 to 1000 is $\frac{1000}{6}=166$

I can not understand why this method works.Can anyone explain me with intuition?

Comment: $6n  \le 1000$ iff and only if  $n \le 1000/6$

Comment: Every sixth number is a multiple of 6.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to know the number of multiples of $x$ between $1$ and $n$. Think of splitting $n$ into distinct, pieces, each of which has size $x$. How whole pieces are there? This works, because a multiple of $x$ will occur every $x$ numbers; i.e. the first multiple is $x$, then $x+x=2x$, then $x+x+x=3x$, and so on.

For example, let's look at how many multiples of $3$ there are less than $13$:

$(1,2,3)$ $(4,5,6)$ $(7,8,9)$ $(10,11,12)$ $(13)$. Then there are $4$ pieces of size $3$, so there are $4$ multiples of three that are between $1$ and $13$.

So how would we count the number of whole pieces? We would divide $n$ by $x$ (because we are splitting $n$ into pieces each of size $x$), then round down to the nearest integer.

To look back at our example: $\left \lfloor {13/3}\right\rfloor=4$.